# NuGet pack after ILMerge is not able to resolve dependences

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, pack, ilmerge

I have the following tools:

- Visual Studio 2017
- ILMerge 2.14.1208
- NuGet.CommandLine 4.5.1
- .NET Framework 4.0

I have a common library called `Common.dll`, and  `MyProject.dll` that depends on `Common.dll` and other additional DLLs called `Lib1.dll` and `Lib2.dll` that in  turn also depend on `Common.dll`.

Now I need to merge all DLLs into a single `MyProject.dll` but internalizing all the dependences so I have done the following in sequence:

ilmerge /log:log.txt /out:Common.dll Common.dll Lib1.dll Lib2.dll

then

`ilmerge /log:log.txt /out:MyProject.dll Common.dll /internalize`

up to now if I include `MyProject.dll` as reference by browsing to the file location in a consuming code, there is no issue, it work just fine, but if I try to pack into a nuget repository (local or remote),

`nuget pack MyProject.nuspec`

now once i install the NuGet package in the consuming code, an exception is raised `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` saying that it `Could not load file or assembly 'Common.dll`

Where am I Wrong?

**EDIT**:
Here is my MyProject.nuspec `MyProject.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProject</id>
    <version>1.0.1.0</version>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <owners></owners>
    <description>
      This is a description
    </description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: What is inside your .nuspec? What is inside the generated .nupkg? I am guessing that the non-ILMerged MyProject.dll is being added to the .nupkg for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added the content  on my .nuspec file in my post. In the .nupkg  in lib/net40 there is a merged version of MyProject.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that from the Common.dll assembly no assembly is requested by name like `Type.GetType("Lib1", "Lib1.ClassName")` if any, change to `Type.GetType("Lib1.ClassName")` before the merge operation